# When admin approves a registered user, I don't want to send a notification email to users

Tags: admin, users, email

When admin approves/unapproves a user, WordPress automatically sends an email about the change.

Here I want to PREVENT it, I DON'T want to send these emails, is there any snippet to add in `functions.php` file as I did it for not sending password change emails,

```
if ( is_admin() )
    add_filter( 'send_password_change_email', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: Aren't you using a plugin via which you approve/desapprove a registered user?

Comment: am using a  plugin 'Profile Builder' @ClemC

Answer (score 0):

This should overwrite the plugable function that sends the email.

```
if ( !function_exists('wp_new_user_notification') ) {
    function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $plaintext_pass = '' ){}
}
```

Comment: Does it prevent emails when admin approves or disapproves a user account too?

Comment: How exactly are you approving or disaproving accounts? That's not a normal feature of WordPress.

Comment: am using a plugin 'profile builder' to do these, there is a module/addon 'User email customization' where I can customize the email, I disabled it. Now WordPress format emails are going. I need to stop these. @Jim Maguire

Comment: I tried your answer, it didn't work @Jim Maguire

Comment: Actually it does work, I tested it. You need to either disable whatever plugins you are using, or make the question about the plugin.